# How can I add MMS functionality to twilio flex UI?

Tags: twilio

Twilio flex UI can sens only SMS. I looking for ways to send and receive MMS in the flex UI.

I have gone through the documentation but I couldnt find any answer.

Does anyone know how can I implement it?

Thanks

Edit -

I am thinking of creating flex plugin.

Also if I am receiving an MMS, I can see image in message log.

So I have tried to access that image with twilio api and add it to CRM container.

Media URL with twilio api - api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts{account sid}/Messages/{message sid}/Media/{media sid}

However, I am geting CORS error for accessing api.twilio from flex.twilio?

How to fix that one?

Comment: What do you have right now? Please provide us your code.

Comment: MMS functionality is not built into Flex out of the box, so you have to build it yourself. Displaying MMS should be a case of overriding the message display to show the media items as well as the message. Sending will require you to implement an upload and storage tool for media. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am thinking of creating flex plugin. Also if I am receiving an MMS, I can see image in message log.

So I have tried to access that image with twilio api and add it to CRM container.

Media URL with twilio api - https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{account sid}/Messages/{message sid}/Media/{media sid}

However, I am geting CORS error for accessing api.twilio from flex.twilio?

How to fix that one?

Comment: Have you made any progress here? I am working on a similar solution and was curious if you have any updates.